# convert map string string to map string list string - Java 7

Tags: java, hibernate, java-7

I have a list of map of string string(`List<Map<String,String>>`) like bellow,

`[{key = "car", value = "bmw"},{key = "car", value = "suzuki"},{key = "car", value = "hyundai"},{key = "bike", value = "honda"},{key = "bike", value = "tvs"}]`

I want to convert to below list of map string list string(`List<Map<String, List<String>>>`) or something equal

`[{key = "car", value = ["bmw","suzuki","hyundai"]},{key = "bike", value = ["honda","tvs"]}]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you populate the List currently? Maybe sharing some code examples would be useful.

Comment: It is just enough with Map<String, List<String>>, you don't need to put it in a list anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Java 8+

#### For singleton maps

Use groupingBy to separate by key and then mapping to get the value of your singleton map

```
Map<String, List<String>> res = 
  list.stream()
    .map(map -> map.entrySet().iterator().next())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      entry -> entry.getKey(),
      Collectors.mapping(
        entry -> entry.getValue(), 
        Collectors.toList()
      )
    )
  );
```

#### For maps with multiple entries

You do the same as above, but flatMap to get all the entries in a single 1-D stream

```
Map<String, List<String>> res = 
  list.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      entry -> entry.getKey(),
      Collectors.mapping(
        entry -> entry.getValue(), 
        Collectors.toList()
      )
    )
  );
```

## Pre-Java 8

#### For maps with multiple entries

You'll have to iterate through each map in the list, and then through the entries of each map. For each entry, check if the key's already there, and if so, add the value to the list associated with that key. If the key's not in the result map, then create a new list there.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, String> m : list) {
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : m.entrySet()) {
    String key = e.getKey();
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
      map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    map.get(key).add(e.getValue());
  }
}
```

#### For singleton maps

For each map in your original list, you find the first entry, and then you do the same as above: add that entry's value to the list that the entry's key maps to, and before that, add a new List to the map if the key doesn't exist there already.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, String> m : list) {
  Map.Entry<String, String> e = m.entrySet().iterator().next();
  String key = e.getKey();
  if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
    map.put(key, new ArrayList<String>());
  }
  map.get(key).add(e.getValue());
}
```

Comment: i am using openjdk version "1.8.0_242". Which above code is not supported. while i am using like this "import java.util.stream.Collectors;".
Please help

Comment: Yes... First I did the same

Comment: Can't import collectors... Version not supported.

Comment: Didn't try that. Will update after trying that .. really thanks for reply and help

Comment: I am using java 7. stream.Collectors is not been supported. is there any way without using collectors ?

Comment: My minor project is already running on Java 7. have to go with Java 7 only. Trying with for loop ... Any logic do you suggest me please.

Comment: Really thanks bro. But error showing as "java: error: incompatible types: ArrayList<Object> cannot be converted to List<String>"

Comment: Thank you so much bro. No word to express my thanks to you. Really thanks for the help .

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you have a list of maps like this:

```
List<Map<String,String>> myListOfMaps = List.of(
        Map.of("car", "bmw"),
        Map.of("car", "suzuki"),
        Map.of("car", "hyundai"),
        Map.of("bike", "honda"),
        Map.of("bike", "tvs")                        
);
```

Then you can use the groupingBy function of streams to do something similar to what you see below.

Stream your list, flatten the stream by streaming over the entrysets, group the entrysets by their keys, map to a list of values

```
Map<String,List<String>> myResultMap = myListOfMaps.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

use result/print ..

```
myResultMap.forEach((k,v)-> {
    System.out.println(k + " : " + v);
});

// car : [bmw, suzuki, hyundai]
// bike : [honda, tvs]
```

Comment: @Eritean: No working for me. That list of throwing error.